# Modal window closing on Escape button only when i click on input

Tags: reactjs, typescript, modal-dialog

My modal window closes on Escape only after i click on input inside this modal. Need to close modal without this manipulations with inputs

```
closeModalEsc(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 27) {
            return this.props.closeModal();
        }
    }
    
    render() {
        const {modal, closeModal} = this.props;
        
        if (modal) {
            return (
                <div className="modal"
                onKeyDown={this.closeModalEsc}>
                    <div className="modal-dialog">
                        <div className="modal-content">
                            <form 
                            action="#"
                            onSubmit={this.onAddName}>
                                <button 
                                className="modal-close"
                                type="button"
                                onClick={closeModal}>
                                    &times;</button>
                                <input 
                                placeholder="What is your name"
                                type="text" 
                                className="form-control modal-input"
                                onChange={this.onUpdateName}
                                value={this.state.textName} />
                                <input 
                                placeholder="Your last name" 
                                type="text" 
                                className="form-control modal-input"
                                onChange={this.onUpdateLastName}
                                value={this.state.textLastName} />
                                <button 
                                className="btn btn-dark"
                                type="submit">
                                    Log In</button>
```

This method from my App.js file, to close modal window

```
closeModal() {
        this.setState({modal: false});
    }
```

Udate: I solved it with adding the listener to document, instead of modal window, and used componentDidMount

Answer (score 0):

The key press event which you are inspecting `e.keyCode` is from a keyboard event. And this keyboard event is raised from a keypress or onChange event which is done from the input controller. In this case the focus is not on the `modal`, that the reason it expects you to click on the input controller.

```
<input 
    placeholder="What is your name"
    type="text" 
    className="form-control modal-input"
    onChange={this.onUpdateName}
    value={this.state.textName} 
/>
<input 
    placeholder="Your last name" 
    type="text" 
    className="form-control modal-input"
    onChange={this.onUpdateLastName}
    value={this.state.textLastName} 
/>
```

The onChange event of either of the input controller trigger `this.onUpdateName` or `this.onUpdateLastName`. These event in turn makes an update or triggers an update to the parent props.

**Solution:** Use `React.creatRef`, to focus on the modal when its opened, listen for keypress and close the modal.

Or you could implement any of your own solution to the problem.